# CSS Grid not effecting html

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I've tried several things for the project divs..

Ideally i would like them to align in a neat block 3*2 or similar.

```css
div {
  text-align: top;
}

#container {
  background: #;
  width: 960px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#header {
  width: 950px;
  background: #rgb(187, 203, 231);
  align-content: center;
}


/* here I am using type selectors to link it to my HTML document*/


/*A HTML element can only have one ID and a web page can only have one HTML 
        element with the same ID*/


/*The following is called a box model, which makes reference to putting a 
         'box' around a HTML element */

#A {
  width: 920px;
  height: 180px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  align-content: center;
  f
}


/*padding creates whitespace around content within margins and borders*/

#B {
  width: 490px;
  height: 500px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  float: right;
}

#C {
  width: 410px;
  height: 725px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}


}
#main {
  width: 940px;
  background: #E80CC7;
  align-content: center;
  f
}

/* Flexbox used for project items within the projectandsamplecode container 
     which is also a "section"*/
#projectsandexamplecode
/*projects are  indiviual boxes*/
#projects {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 50px 100px;
  background-image: url("../Images/a.jpeg");
}

/* insert flex row*/
#D {
  width: 247px;
  height: 138px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}
#E {
  width: 247px;
  height: 138px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}
#F {
  width: 247px;
  height: 138px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}
#G {
  width: 247px;
  height: 138px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}
#H {
  width: 247px;
  height: 138px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}
#I {
  width: 247px;
  height: 138px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}
#socialmedia {
  justify-content: left;
  background: #40FF40;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
#l {
  float: left;
  background: #40FF40;
}
#m {
  float: left;
  background: #40FF40;
}
#n {
  float: left;
  background: #40FF40;
}
#o {
  float: left;
  background: #40FF40;
}
#p {
  float: left;
  background: #40FF40;
}
#footer {
  background: #A005FF;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<head>

  <title></title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css1.css">

</head>

<body>

  <!-- this is my div section in a comment web html of basic a,b,c structure to box elements-->

  <div id="container">

    <div id="header">

      <div id="A"> <img id="headerpic" src="images/download.jpeg" ; width: "940"; height: "150"x;></div>

      <div id="B"><img src="images/computopia.jpg" width="280" ; height="400"></div>
      <div id="C">Site description History and background"
        <p><cite>"Bad programmers worry about the code. Good programmers worry about data structures and their relationships"-Linus Trovalds</cite></p>
      </div>
      <a href="page2.html" CV</a>
    </div>

    <div id="Projects and example code">

      <div id="projects">

        <div id="D">
          <Project 1>Project 1</div>
        <div id="E">
          <Project 2>Project 2</div>
        <div id="F">
          <Project 3>Project 3</div>
        <div id="G">
          <Project 4>Project4</div>
        <div id="H">
          <Project 5>Project 5</div>
        <div id="H">
          <Project 6>Project 6</div>



      </div>

    </div>
    <div=id="socialmedia" social media>

      <div id="l">Facbook</div>
      <div id="m"><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/chris-hudson-23a37118/"> Linkedin</div>
                                                                           <div id="n">Stackoverflow</div>
                                                                           <div id="o">GIT-Hub</div>
                                                                           <div id="p"><a href = secondwebpage.html></a>CV</div>

  </div>



  <div id="footer">



  </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you maybe put the code in a fiddle then i would be able to assist.

Comment: Well you have some unclosed Divs in there. I suggest you fix your HTML first

Comment: Hi PeterJoe, no problem.. im a bit new to fiddle also? does it work like a repository? ive pasted in https://jsfiddle.net/C2100/8msgjchy/1/#&togetherjs=cU59kRT13K many thanks